# SQL upgrade fails on 5.14.2 to 5.15.0 on Joomla

Tags: upgrade

In upgrading from civi 5.14.2 to 5.15.0, the SQL update fails. In civi log, I get:

Jul 08 09:48:13  [info] Running task: Cleanup old files
Jul 08 09:48:13  [info] Running task: Checking extensions
Jul 08 09:48:14  [info] Running task: Begin Upgrade to 5.15.alpha1
Jul 08 09:48:15  [info] Running task: Upgrade DB to 5.15.alpha1
Jul 08 09:48:15  [info] Running task: Upgrade DB to 5.15.alpha1: SQL
Jul 08 09:48:16  [info] Running task: Fix errant deferred revenue settings

And then sql update dies and nothing else in log.

Relevant environment settings:

Database Version    5.5.5-10.0.38-MariaDB
Database Connection Collation   utf8mb4_general_ci
PHP Version 7.2.19

Any suggestions?

Here's the error log from civiCRM:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y4NWik-4fVWjflifgOIGsSXiU3NN0S2O/view?usp=sharing

And this is the on-screen error:
[image]

And here's a video walkthrough of the upgrade process, including which steps fail during the DB update:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15MonHfW2TW_RbfhvbY2FIdB2Uao7poSH/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Could you please check your log file in the ConfigAndLog directory?  There's likely to be a SQL error and backtrace.  Please update your question with whatever you find!

Comment: I've added the error log -- there are only six lines in it. Also added screenshot of on-screen error message.

Comment: I just enabled full Debugging in civiCRM, which then gives the option to skip queries that trigger errors. I skipped several errors, which are recorded in the attached error log above -- the update then "completed", but I'm concerned why some of these queries failed... and has my update really been successful?

Comment: Your error log doesn't indicate which ones you skipped?

Comment: I've added a video walk-through of the update process, showing stop points in the DB update.

Comment: Any thoughts about whether these skipped updates are anything for me to worry about?

Comment: I've tried the update with 5.15.1, and issue persists.

Comment: I also saw this on upgrading from 5.14.1 to 5.15.1 (Joomla 3.9.10). I rolled back the database to my backup, and also disabled extensions APIv4, Mosaico and Flexmailer (as I'd been playing with those just prior). Didn't get the error when I tried upgrading to 5.15.1 again. By any chance do you have any of those extensions enabled?

Comment: I do indeed have those enabled. I will disable them and test, and report back here with results.

Comment: So yes, this is the issue. With those 3 extensions disabled the database update runs successfully, and then I can re-enable those extensions after the update.

Comment: I disabled all extensions having seen the error below, but the upgrade still hangs at

Executed: Running task: Fix cache key column name in prev next cache

The CiviCRM error log shows

[info] Running task: Update smart groups where jcalendar fields have been converted to datepicker

but no  error message.

Comment: The PHP error log starts with:
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: CRM_Upgrade in ...\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Queue\Service.php on line 136

Comment: I looked further at the log and found an unserialize error in a saved search record.  Once I had fixed the corrupted serialised string the installation ran OK.

Answer (score 1):

I see from your video that you're failing on the 5.15.alpha1 SQL, and on.

The first one has two SQL statements.  Essentially, the statuses for a contribution ("Pending", "Complete", etc.) and for recurring contributions have been the same - but moving forward they'll each have their own list.  The two SQL statements create an option group along with values to support this.

Run this SQL: `select id, name from civicrm_option_group WHERE name = 'contribution_recur_status';`

You should get back one result.  If you have no results, that's a problem:

```
+-----+---------------------------+
| id  | name                      |
+-----+---------------------------+
| 138 | contribution_recur_status |
+-----+---------------------------+
```

Then run this SQL: `select cov.id, cov.option_group_id, cov.name, cov.label, cov.value from civicrm_option_value cov JOIN civicrm_option_group cog ON cov.option_group_id = cog.id WHERE cog.name = 'contribution_recur_status';`

You should get back some number of results - I get 12, you may have more:

```
+------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-------+
| id   | option_group_id | name           | label          | value |
+------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-------+
| 1884 |             138 | Completed      | Completed      | 1     |
| 1885 |             138 | Pending        | Pending        | 2     |
| 1886 |             138 | Cancelled      | Cancelled      | 3     |
| 1887 |             138 | Failed         | Failed         | 4     |
| 1888 |             138 | In Progress    | In Progress    | 5     |
| 1889 |             138 | Overdue        | Overdue        | 6     |
| 1890 |             138 | Refunded       | Refunded       | 7     |
| 1891 |             138 | Partially paid | Partially paid | 8     |
| 1892 |             138 | Pending refund | Pending refund | 9     |
| 1893 |             138 | Chargeback     | Chargeback     | 10    |
| 1899 |             138 | Processing     | Processing     | 11    |
| 1900 |             138 | Failing        | Failing        | 12    |
+------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+-------+
```

You're also failing on "Fix cache key column name in prev next cache". 
That's trying to run this SQL, so also run this command manually:
`ALTER TABLE civicrm_prevnext_cache CHANGE COLUMN  cacheKey cachekey VARCHAR(255) COMMENT 'Unique path name for cache element of the searched item';`